# UWP, open very small Page/Frame

Tags: c#, uwp

I'm writting an app which has 2 windows:
- main: regular UWP window
- helper: always on top, very small to show only texts like: started, paused ..
I can't force 'helper' window to be small. 'Always on top' in this window works fine.

I'm following UWP samples:
- always on top mode works from: 
[uwp samples / app window / overlay](https://github.com/microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/blob/master/Samples/AppWindow/cs/Scenario4_CompactOverlay.xaml.cs)
- making window small (fails) from: [uwp samples / app window / size](https://github.com/microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/blob/master/Samples/AppWindow/cs/Scenario3_Size.xaml.cs)

My current code is like below.
Any ideas how to make 'helper' window small?

```
public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
{
    private AppWindow appWindow;
    private Frame appWindowFrame = new Frame();

    async void ShowHelperWindow()
    {
        // Is CompactOverlay supported for our main window?
        // If so, it will be supported for a new window as well.
        // If it isn't, it will not be supported for new windows either so we cannot proceed.
        if (!ApplicationView.GetForCurrentView().IsViewModeSupported(ApplicationViewMode.CompactOverlay))
        {
            return;
        }

        if (appWindow == null)
        {
            // Create a new AppWindow
            appWindow = await AppWindow.TryCreateAsync();
            // Make sure we release the reference to this window, and release XAML resources, when it's closed
            appWindow.Closed += delegate { appWindow = null; appWindowFrame.Content = null; };
            // Is CompactOverlay supported for this AppWindow? If not, then stop.
            if (appWindow.Presenter.IsPresentationSupported(AppWindowPresentationKind.CompactOverlay))
            {
                // Create a new frame for the window
                // Navigate the frame to the CompactOverlay page inside it.
                appWindowFrame.Navigate(typeof(TimerStatusPage));

                var size = new Size(192, 48);
                WindowManagementPreview.SetPreferredMinSize(appWindow, new Size(192, 48));
                // Request the size of our window
                appWindow.RequestSize(size);

                // Attach the frame to the window
                ElementCompositionPreview.SetAppWindowContent(appWindow, appWindowFrame);
                // Let's set the title so that we can tell the windows apart
                appWindow.Title = "size:" + size;
                // Request the Presentation of the window to CompactOverlay
                bool switched = appWindow.Presenter.RequestPresentation(AppWindowPresentationKind.CompactOverlay);
                if (switched)
                {
                    // If the request was satisfied, show the window
                    await appWindow.TryShowAsync();
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            await appWindow.TryShowAsync();
        }

    }


    ... rest of class
```

Comment: For UWP it's more idiomatic to create a panel in the main window to hold a helper, not create a separate window. This sounds like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/); why must you create a separate window?